On vs mora – which of the terms is used more commonly in Japanese?
Do the words "on" (音) and "mōra" (モーラ) mean the same thing? Which one of them would be more familiar to a Japanese person, e.g. which one is used in Japanese schools to analyze the language?

Familiar to an average Japanese person who is not trained in linguistics? Terms used in high school and by linguistics researchers are different.

@YusukeMatsubara yes, familiar to a person with general education, not a researcher in linguistics.

People usually use 音【おん】 in everyday conversation, but 拍【はく】 is also widely recognized when they want to be more precise or technical. Laypeople generally do not know the term モーラ at all.

FWIW, non-linguistic-geeks generally don't know the word "mora" in English, either.

@EiríkrÚtlendi right, but that's because we don't use mora to analyze modern English. I would guess however, that I could use the word "syllable" in a casual conversation in English.

My point is more that "mora" is a term of art in linguistics that is not commonly known outside of academic circles.
